# tic tac toe capture css ( assistance )

Tags: css

Just redoing our captcha.

Demo: http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/ttt/422.php

Anyhoo the css is as follows:

```
.funcaptcha { width: 81px; overflow: hidden; float: left; margin-right: 0px; }
.funcaptcha a { display: inline-block; background: url("http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/ttt/images/ttt-small.png"); margin: 2px 2px 0 0; float: left; }
.funcaptcha a.circle { background-position: 0px -29px; }
.funcaptcha a.cross { background-position: -29px -83px; }
.funcaptcha a.empty { background-position: -0px 0px; }
.funcaptcha a.marked,
.funcaptcha a:hover { background-position: -29px 0px; }
.funcaptcha .box { display: block; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; width: 25px; height: 25px; }
```

Contains php, so unable to do a fiddle. But My css positioning is just off a tad, any suggestions ?

the ttt-small.png is:

[image]

Comment: I think your CSS is correct... but your sprite needs work.

Comment: Now that you've posted the image, you'll notice that the bottom layer is 25 pixels tall, and the top layer is 26 pixels tall.  Fix the sprite.  : )

Comment: @John, post your answer if you think that's the problem.

Comment: John I never noticed that , good onya

Comment: @422 - Amongst other things I'm a designer.  I'm trained to see things at pixel-level boundaries.  : )

Comment: @john , I am goggle eyed from looking at poxy images. Working off two monitors I didnt see ( in my crappy resolution 2nd monitor ) the bleed from images. All images fixed now, just the friggin css needs that little extra tweak. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that it can be marked answered....

Bottom layer is 25 pixels tall and the top layer is 26.  Sprite needs to be fixed.

Comment: marked best answer, not cos it fixed our issue, but highlighted an issue I had totally overlooked. Well done

Answer (score 1):

Here's an editable jsFiddle with the HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/WhG5L/

Comment: Cheers. Updated with my latest css. Isnt 100% though :( http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/WhG5L/1/ Cheers for fiddling it Ryan

Comment: It should be easy to fix the CSS if it's still not working. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: seems to be 1 pixel out on the second column. If you look really really closely. I can live with it tho

Comment: The anchor(s) with a class of `cross` had improper background position(s). I've updated the CSS in the jsFiddle. Enjoy! http://jsfiddle.net/WhG5L/2/